# Multiple draggable/sortable elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, html, uikit, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a template (simplified version below) that's using divs to look like a table. I am looking for a solution that allows to drag the whole 'column' - all 'cells' with the same class and rearrange the order of the 'columns'.
Is there any other library that allows that or any possible modification to UIKit?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- UIkit CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.16.17/dist/css/uikit.min.css" />

<!-- UIkit JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.16.17/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.16.17/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
  <style>

    .cell-col {
      width: 100px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="table">
    <div class="row uk-flex">
        <div class="cell-col cell-col-1">Content col1 row1</div><div class="cell-col cell-col-2">Content col2 row1</div><div class="cell-col cell-col-3">Content col3 row1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uk-flex">
        <div class="cell-col cell-col-1">Content col1 row2</div><div class="cell-col cell-col-2">Content col2 row2</div><div class="cell-col cell-col-3">Content col3 row2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uk-flex">
        <div class="cell-col cell-col-1">Content col1 row3</div><div class="cell-col cell-col-2">Content col2 row3</div><div class="cell-col cell-col-3">Content col3 row3</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using UIKit library, but their 'sortable' feature doesn't have that functionality 'off the shelf'. And I don't want to use jQuery UI as it seems it's being maintained anymore.

Comment: If you were asking a question about how you could compose that functionality yourself (along with enough code to demonstrate the problem(s) you're having) that would be fine, and perfectly on-topic. Unfortunately we don't give recommendations due to the rapidly changing nature of the internet and the rise/fall of the various resources around the net.